# Speed of CPLEX vs CPLEX using SCIP

Tags: scipy, cplex, gurobi, scip, pulp

I am new to LP and have only briefly used `PuLP` in Python.

1. Why is there a speed difference between `SCIP 3.2.1 - CPLEX 12.63` and `CPLEX 12.6.3`? Doesn't SCIP still use CPLEX for solving?
2. Why will someone use SCIP with CPLEX solver, instead of using CPLEX directly?

[image]

Comment: Some remark: [cbc](https://projects.coin-or.org/Cbc) (one of the best open-source MIP-solvers) will be typically the default-solver for [pulp](https://github.com/coin-or/pulp). At least within the windows-distribution.

Answer (score 15):

#### What is this difference about

This plot is not showing a LP-benchmark, but a **Mixed-integer programming benchmark**.

Mixed-integer programming solvers typically use a **branch-and-cut**-based algorithm (including heuristics and co.), where **a lot** of **relaxations** are solved (in sequence; treating binary-/integer-variables as continuous resulting in an **LP-problem**).

One decision then is to choose how to solve these relaxed subproblems. The most simple decision (there are many more; e.g. tuning the **Simplex-algorithm**'s parameters; it get's even more complex when solving problems with nonlinear-conic objectives) is to choose the LP-solver.

**SoPlex** is a LP-solver implementation by the SCIP-team. Meaning:

- SCIP - SoPlex will use SCIP's algorithm for MIP (handling branching, cut-generation and co.) using SoPlex as solver for the internal LP-subproblems
- SCIP - CPLEX will use SCIP's algorithm for MIP using CPLEX as solver for the internal LP-subproblems

#### Why using SCIP with CPLEX (instead of using a pure CPLEX approach)

The why is not that easy to explain.

- **Keep in mind, that all MIP-solvers are heuristics-based and on some problems SCIP will be faster than CPLEX** (despite the underlying LP-solver selected).

  Keywords for some theory: **NP-hardness** (of MIP) and the **No free lunch theorem**

  - Faster could mean: faster due to the MIP-based strategies, not the speed of the underlying LP-solver so that you may even gain an overall speedup using CPLEX on the subproblems!
- The two solvers (MIP-solvers) are probably also much **different** in regards to **parameters & accessibility (of internal algorithmic components)**. It's obvious, that you can tune SCIP in a much more general way than CPLEX (because it's open source)
- As **mattmilten** mentioned in the comments: SCIP and CPLEX are also different in regards to the support of problem-classes which can be solved. One example of this might be the possibility for some [special nonlinear-constraints](http://scip.zib.de/#features) (resulting in a MINLP). Using SCIP for these kind of problems, can still use CPLEX' LP-solver internally (same arguments as above)

Comment: Worth noting is that SCIP can solve a wide variety of problem classes - more than CPLEX - and sometimes it may be of advantage to still use CPLEX as LP solver while solving a nonconvex MINLP for instance.

Comment: @mattmilten I just added one remark, that sometimes the MIP-based algorithm is faster and an additional speedup could be obtained by using CPLEX' LP-solver for the subproblems. I agree with everything you said.